# Why should we not return a response in an HTTP DELETE request?

Tags: api, http, endpoint, http-get, http-delete

At my company we have a DELETE endpoint which (obviously) deletes some data that the user selects on the client side. Currently we are doing another get request to refresh the data on this page after the deletion requests completes successfully (So we don't have two conflicting states on client/server side).

A developer at our company wants to now change the DELETE endpoint to return the updated state after the data is successfully deleted, so we can just use this response value to update our client side.

This makes sense to me (As we can avoid another GET call) but from other [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970523/restful-what-should-a-delete-response-body-contain/50792918) the general consensus is that we should return an empty response.

Can someone explain to me why this is the case? I've looked around it seems like people are mostly saying 'because that is how REST is supposed to be' which doesn't really seem like a good reason.